# Dual-Boot Android Tiramisu?

Tags: operating-system, x86-emulation, android-tiramisu

So I know this might be a bit of a long shot but, would it theoretically be possible to dual-boot Android Tiramisu with Windows 11?

My computer isn't able to handle Android Studio emulation past about Pie (even that is slow) and it makes testing hard. I tried primeOS and  blissOS, but those aren't really good alternatives to app testing. I used the hyper-V manager to load androidx86 and it went somewhere but it is unable to load webpages.